# My browser returns me to the previous page when i click on an link

Tags: javascript, web, browser, frontend, tailwind-css

I have a website (with html, css, js, tailwind css) and I implemented the navigation (menus) using links, which menu items (links) other than a menu item (link) link to a page with Different serach query value as below

```
<ul class="basis-2/5 hidden sm:flex sm:basis-1/2 md:basis-2/5 justify-evenly items-center text-base">
                <li class="relative font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-bottom-2 after:-translate-1/2 hover:after:inline-block hover:text-secondary dark:hover:text-white transition-colors duration-200 hover:texet-secondary after:w-1 after:h-1 after:rounded-md after:bg-secondary dark:after:bg-gray-100 after:hidden">
                    <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menLiElem relative font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-bottom-2 after:-translate-1/2 hover:after:inline-block hover:text-secondary dark:hover:text-white transition-colors duration-200 after:w-1 after:h-1 after:rounded-md after:bg-secondary dark:after:bg-gray-100 after:hidden">
                    <a href="./products.html?t=men">Men</a>
                </li>
                <li class="womenLiElem relative font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-bottom-2 after:-translate-1/2 hover:after:inline-block hover:text-secondary dark:hover:text-white transition-colors duration-200 after:w-1 after:h-1 after:rounded-md after:bg-secondary dark:after:bg-gray-100 after:hidden">
                    <a href="./products.html?t=women">Women</a>
                </li>
                <li class="kidsLiElem relative font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-bottom-2 after:-translate-1/2 hover:after:inline-block hover:text-secondary dark:hover:text-white transition-colors duration-200 after:w-1 after:h-1 after:rounded-md after:bg-secondary dark:after:bg-gray-100 after:hidden">
                    <a href="./products.html?t=kids">Kids</a>
                </li>
                <li class="allLiElem ">
                    <a href="./products.html?t=all">Collections</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And in the products.html page, I have come from
`location.search`
I got the value sent and according to it, I give active style to the selected menu item and display the product to the user as below

```
 let locationElems = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
    let productType = !locationElems.size ? 'all' : 
                    ['all' , 'men' , 'women' , 'kids'].includes(locationElems.get('t').toLowerCase()) ? locationElems.get('t').toLowerCase() : null


    groupBtn.querySelector('span').innerHTML = productType || 'All'

    let menuElems = null
    if(productType && productType != 'all'){
        menuElems = document.querySelectorAll(`.${productType.toLowerCase()}LiElem`)
    } else {
        menuElems = document.querySelectorAll('.allLiElem')
    }

    menuElems.forEach(menuElem => menuElem.classList.add('active'))
```

and i filter products As follows

```
allProducts = productType == 'all' ? [...products] : products.filter(product => product.productCategory.toLowerCase() == productType)
        let filteredProducts = allProducts
```

Now all the links work, but when I click on the link and the collections menu item, it returns me to the previous history page.
What should I do to solve this problem?

I don't think there is a problem, that's why I tried it with a number of browsers and it gave the same result as before and I have no idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are all the classes `relative font-bold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 after:absolute after:left-1/2 after:-bottom-2 after:-translate-1/2 hover:after:inline-block hover:text-secondary dark:hover:text-white transition-colors duration-200 hover:texet-secondary after:w-1 after:h-1 after:rounded-md after:bg-secondary dark:after:bg-gray-100 after:hidden` at at relevant for your query?